# Javascript regex with variable

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I have the following string in a variable named `js`:

```
some code here
/* start-rotateControlOptions */
some more code here
on multiple
lines
/* end-rotateControlOptions */
some code here
```

And I want to end up with:

```
some code here
some code here
```

Basically escape everything between these 2 specific comments.

The following works:

```
js = js.replace(/\/\* start-rotateControlOptions \*\/([\s\S]*)\/\* end-rotateControlOptions \*\//, '');
```

But now I need to have the `rotateControlOptions` as a variable.

This is what I have tried to no avail:

```
js = escapeCode(js, 'rotateControlOptions');

function escapeCode(js, identifier) {

    var re = new RegExp("/\/\* start-" + identifier + " \*\/([\s\S]*)\/\* end-" + identifier + " \*\//");
    js = js.replace(re, '');
    return js;
}
```

What am I doing wrong? I get no error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Escape all the backslahes one more time and you don't need to add the forward slash delimiter inside the `RegExp` constructor.

```
var re = new RegExp("/\\* start-" + identifier + " \\*/([\\s\\S]*)/\\* end-" + identifier + " \\*/");
```

**Example:**

```
> var str = 'some code here\n/* start-rotateControlOptions */\nsome more code here\non multiple\nlines\n/* end-rotateControlOptions */\nsome code here';
> var re = new RegExp("/\\* start-" + identifier + " \\*/([\\s\\S]*)/\\* end-" + identifier + " \\*/\\n");
undefined
> console.log(str.replace(re, ''))
some code here
some code here
```

Comment: Excellent! Thanks a bunch! One more thing though: this seems to leave a blank line after what has been replaced in my string. Can I avoid that?

Comment: Mmmh thanks. That works but somehow breaks my code indentation on the next line (I am trying to remove parts of a script and display the output on a web page). New lines in the code are added with PHP with `"\r\n"`. Any idea?

Comment: then add `[\\r\\n]+` at the last. I suggest you to add `\\s+` instead of a single whitespace because there may be a possibility of tabs instead of a whitespace..

Comment: `new RegExp("/\\* start-" + identifier + " \\*/([\\s+\\S]*)/\\* end-" + identifier + " \\*/[\\r\\n]+");` right? Output is still the same. To illustrate: http://oi62.tinypic.com/zx5q1i.jpg

Comment: Nevermind. This seems to be an issue with google-prettify. Thanks again.